# Why does c# Aggregate evaluate returns an incorrect value?

Tags: aggregate

```
List<decimal>scontiList = new List<decimal>();
scontiList.Add((decimal)50.0m);
scontiList.Add((decimal)50.0m);
scontiList.Add((decimal)50.0m);
scontiList.Add((decimal)50.0m);
scontiList.Add((decimal)50.0m);
scontiList.Add((decimal)50.0m);
scontiList.Add((decimal)50.0m);
scontiList.Add((decimal)50.0m);
scontiList.Add((decimal)50.0m);
scontiList.Add((decimal)50.0m);
scontiList.Add((decimal)50.0m);
scontiList.Add((decimal)50.0m);
scontiList.Add((decimal)50.0m);
decimal cento = (decimal)100.0d;
decimal ris = scontiList.Aggregate((decimal)0.0m, (a, b) =(decimal)((decimal)1 - ((decimal)a / (decimal)cento)) * (decimal)((decimal)1 - ((decimal)b / (decimal)cento)));
```

->    ris 0.4975125

Why is in that case ris = 0,4975125 ?
correct is 0.125

Comment: Who says it's 0.125? I just bashed it into excel and got the same answer LINQ gave you. Do you understand the aggregate function? Please add info to your question that indicates how you think Aggregate is supposed to work in order for you to get 0.125

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate starts with a seed value, runs the function you specify and stores the result back into the accumulator. It then moves on, repeating this loop

Your seed is 0 (the value given to current_value for the first iteration)

Your operation is `(1 - current_value/100) * (1 - next_value/100)`

Your values are all 50, hence your operation is really: `curr = (1 - curr / 0.5) * 0.5`

The progression is thus:

```
Seed: (1 - 0/100) * 0.5 = 0.5
Step 1: (1 - 0.5/100) * 0.5 = 0.4975
Step 2: (1 - 0.4975/100) * 0.5 = 0.4975125
```

As you can see it's settling on 0.4975. It will never get to 0.125. That decimal number will get longer and longer (more digits), but it'll always be about 0.4975